# Video over HTTP-can you tell if a video is being downloaded or it is being watched?

Tags: video, download, streaming, http, youtube

How can Youtube or Vimeo etc for example, tell that you are downloading a video rather than watching it?

What kind of HTTP request/headers is fired in each case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think they can - which is why despite being in breach of (at least) Youtubes T&C's this practice is rife.
There are no inherent protocol differences between a download and stream, but there are some comon things a server could use -

1. The number of chunks downloaded simultaneously.
2. The speed the download occurs at.
3. The size if the download relative to the reported screen size.
4. Method of download - eg a streaming program may use TCP while reporting to be Chrome - when Chrome actually use QUICK
5. Interpreting of Javascript
6. Simultaneous downloads of multiple videos, or inadequate delays between downloads.

Ofcourse all of these can be emulated by a downloader - creating something of a cat and mouse game

There is, however, a biggie I dont believe is used by Youtube or Vimeo (but Netflix does) - DRM. This requires specific program or browser support, and us much harder to circumvent/immitate. Ofcourse, ths creates costs to deploy and rcreates barriers to view - and I expect Youtube etc business model is such that its not optimal for them.